# How do I make lots of websites of the different permutations of Z1189?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to find the different websites of a permuatet letters. This is for geocaching. So for example I need to make a link like this: http://geocaching.com/geocache/GCZ1189
So I would like the 120 different permutations to open in my browser. The only difference is the "Z1189" the rest of the link is going to stay the same :)

So i've found this code online. And tried the last part as a test. But without sucsess.

```py
# Python function to print permutations of a given list 
def permutation(lst): 

    # If lst is empty then there are no permutations 
    if len(lst) == 0: 
        return [] 

    # If there is only one element in lst then, only 
    # one permuatation is possible 
    if len(lst) == 1: 
        return [lst] 

    # Find the permutations for lst if there are 
    # more than 1 characters 

    l = [] # empty list that will store current permutation 

    # Iterate the input(lst) and calculate the permutation 
    for i in range(len(lst)): 
       m = lst[i] 

       # Extract lst[i] or m from the list.  remLst is 
       # remaining list 
       remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:] 

       # Generating all permutations where m is first 
       # element 
       for p in permutation(remLst): 
           l.append([m] + p) 
    return l 

data = list('Z1189') 
for p in permutation(data): 
    print (p)


#I've made this below. Not working as I wanting it to though
for p in permutation(data):
    o = list(p)
    o = ''.join(o)
    permutation(data).append(o)
    print(o)
```

So I want it to open all the different web pages that can be done with this permutation. SO a link with Z1189. But the http://geocaching.com/geocache/GC. Is going to be like on every page. So as here. When I use the console to type "print permutation(data)" it shows me only a long text. With the stuff i just deleted. Like [, ] and stuff. Can anyone help me?

Comment: append to a new list, not `permutation(data)`

Comment: Python already ships with a builtin permutation function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations